building qtwebengine:x64-windows failed
I want to use Qt in my Visual Studio project. And I decided to install Qt using vcpkg. But at the installation stage, qtwebengine causes an error:
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    qtwebengine[core,default-features]:x64-windows@6.7.2
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Compiler found: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exeRestored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\d1orn\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 78.7 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/1 qtwebengine[core,default-features]:x64-windows@6.7.2...
Building qtwebengine[core,default-features]:x64-windows@6.7.2...
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:127 (message):
    Command failed: C:/vcpkg/downloads/tools/python/python-3.11.8-x64/Scripts/pip.exe install virtualenv --no-warn-script-location
    Working Directory: C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/qtwebengine
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-get-python-packages/x_vcpkg_get_python_packages.cmake:62 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/qtwebengine/portfile.cmake:69 (x_vcpkg_get_python_packages)
  scripts/ports.cmake:192 (include)

I tried to manually execute the command C:/vcpkg/downloads/tools/python/python-3.11.8-x64/Scripts/pip.exe install virtualenv --no-warn-script-location in the directory C:/vcpkg/buildtrees/qtwebengine, but it gives the following:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\d1orn\vcpkg\downloads\tools\python\python-3.11.8-x64\python.exe"  "C:\vcpkg\downloads\tools\python\python-3.11.8-x64\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv --no-warn-script-location': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.

Before that, the error described here occurred, and I moved the vcpkg folder to the root of the C drive.

Do you really need qtwebengine? I mean, with vcpkg you can depend on individual qt modules and skip big libs like qtwebengine.
